# Secure authentication with GWT and GAE over https?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, https, rpc

I want to implement a custom user authentication system in my appengine app.  I don't want to use sessions.  I'm a newbie in this area, so I have two basic questions:

1: Is it secure to just send a username and password with every single RPC over https?  What do I need to do to keep that username and password secure on the client end?

2: How do I tell GWT to use https when it makes its requests?

I don't know much about security, so please don't spare me any "obvious" details.

Thanks!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ seems to answer question 1 with "yes," and "cookies."  Still frustratingly elusive is the answer to question 2.

Comment: How did your implementation work out?  Did you have any issues with having to send the login credentials for every request?

Comment: It's been working great for three months!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Watching the process with firebug shows that all RPCs are happening over the same protocol that the host page was requested with.  This seems to be required for same-site-origin rules, so I'm going to assume that my answers are

1: Yes, but it's slower

2: GWT automatically uses https when the host page was requested w/ https

Answer (score 2):

1. Sending username and password over HTTPS is secure, but nobody does this for every request, because some day you may forget/need to send a request through HTTP. Also, keeping password in memory will attract XSS hackers. One unnoticed XSS vulnerability will expose passwords. Usually, developers keep either session-id or XSRF-token in memory and send it with each request.
2. Look at  at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Secure_URLs
3. Don't forget about XSRF protection, you need to implement it for requests that change something (not read-only).

Answer (score 1):

On GAE you can also use Google User Services API http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview.html . It's very intuitive and you won't need to know security details.

Comment: Thanks, but I need more control than that API provides (I want to create my own users, not rely on an external authentication method).